# Import multi-nested subfolders in python neatly

Tags: python, import, module, directory, sys

I have the following directory structure:

```py
.
├── main.py
└── subfolder1
    ├── file1.py # def hello(): print("hello")
    ├── __init__.py 
    └── subfolder2
        ├── file2.py # def world(): print("world")
        └── __init__.py
```

I'm trying to be to access functions from both `subfolder1/file.1py` and `subfolder/subfolder2/file2.py`.

I have an empty `__init__.py` in each nested folder as per the documentation I could find. I'm assuming that's necessary. (Update: I've just now removed the `__init__.py`'s from both subfolders and it still works. I thought having this was necessary?)

Contents of `main.py`:

```py
import subfolder1.file1
import subfolder1.subfolder2.file2

subfolder1.file1.hello()
subfolder1.subfolder2.file2.world()
```

When I execute `main.py`, both functions are called correctly. But the syntax is more cumbersome than I'd like, I don't want to have to repeatedly specify directory paths in subsequent imports.

I've tried doing something like

```py
import subfolder1 as sub1
import sub1.subfolder2 as sub2

sub1.file1.hello()
sub2.file2.world()
```

But my IDE's Pylance alerts me that `Import "sub1.subfolder2" could not be resolved` and the terminal outputs on execution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/project/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sub1.subfolder2 as sub2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub1'
```

I've seen online the `sys.append('/path/to/subfolder')` method, but I don't like having to take up a line of code before every multi-nested import. It defeats the purpose, as my goal is to avoid repeatedly typing out paths, whether in the `import` statement or a `sys.append()` method.

Are there any ways to do multi-level modularization more elgantly/succintly in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Nice [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) !

About `__init__.py` files, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for), but the gist is :

- They were required in Python2 and Python3.3 to indicate that a **directory** is a **python package** (from which you can import), but it is now optional (Python >= 3.4).
- It defines what ends up in your module `subfolder1` when you do `import subfolder1`.

See the [Python language reference about **packages**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages).

Given your initial architecture, you can see what does your `sub1` module contains/defines using [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) :

```py
# file: main.py
import subfolder1 as sub1
print(dir(sub1))
# ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

As all of these are **dunder methods** related to the Python import machinery, it should not come as a surprise that `sub1.subfolder2` fails : there is actually no `subfolder2` in `sub1`.

Contrast with this example :

```py
import logging
print(dir(logging))
# logging stuff :
#   [..., 'CRITICAL', 'DEBUG', 'ERROR', 'FATAL', 'Logger', 'getLogger', ...
# regular module/package/import stuff :
#    '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__',
#    '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__status__', '__version__', ...
# and names of other modules :
#    'os', 're', ..., 'sys', 'threading', 'time', ...]

# which means I can do :
print(logging.DEBUG)
# 10
print(logging.__author__)
# Vinay Sajip <vinay_sajip@red-dove.com>
print(logging.sys.version)
# 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 18:17:56)
# [GCC 9.3.0]
import sys
print(sys.version)
# 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 18:17:56)
# [GCC 9.3.0]
print(logging.sys is sys)
# True
```

If you take a look at the implementation for your (C)Python library `sys`, for example using your IDE's "go-to-definition" you will get an `__init__.py` file (mine is `/usr/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py`). And it defines exactly what `dir` listed to me.

(*I chose `logging` because it is implemented in pure Python, while other libraries may not*)

Your `__init__.py` file defines what will be in `subfolder1` when you do just `import subfolder1`.

How to control what ends up in your library ?

```py
import logging
from logging import *
print(DEBUG)  # 10
print(sys.version)  # NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

because

```
import logging
print("DEBUG" in logging.__all__)  # True
print("sys" in logging.__all__)  # False
```

Citing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842/11384184) about `__all__` :

> It's a list of public objects of that module, as interpreted by import *. It overrides the default of hiding everything that begins with an underscore.

Now, to answer your question "how to import neatly" :

```py
# file: subfolder1/__init__.py
from . import file1
```

```py
# file: subfolder1/subfolder2/__init__.py
from . import file2
```

```py
# file: main.py
import subfolder1 as sub1
import subfolder1.subfolder2 as sub2
sub1.file1.hello()
sub2.file2.world()
```

You can't `import sub1.subfolder2` because Python won't find a `sub1` package (unless by messing with [loaders](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loaders)).
But you can import `subfolder1.subfolder2` because there exist a directory `subfolder1/subfolder2`.

What you could also do is :

```py
# file: subfolder1/__init__.py
from . import subfolder2
from . import file1
```

```py
# file: main.py
import subfolder1 as sub1
sub1.file1.hello()
sub1.subfolder2.file2.world()
```

or else :

```py
# file: subfolder1/__init__.py
from . import subfolder2 as sub2
from . import file1
```

```py
# file: main.py
import subfolder1 as sub1
sub1.file1.hello()
sub1.sub2.file2.world()
```